# Update cartesianIndex

Tags: julia

I am stuck in a problem. I want to update my cartesian index.

I have a matrix (`x`) 200x6 that is binary. 1 if assigned, 0 otherwise. I want to find the cartesian index of when `x` is 1 in the first 3 columns and in the last 3 elements.

I have the following code:

```
index_right = findall( x -> x == 1, sol.x_assignment[:,1:3])
index_left = findall( x -> x == 1, sol.x_assignment[:,4:6])
index_left
```

However `index_right` is correct, `index_left` is wrong as it returns index between 1,2,3 instead of 4,5,6

```
CartesianIndex(2, 1)
CartesianIndex(3, 1)
CartesianIndex(10, 2)
CartesianIndex(11, 1)
```

Expected output:

```
CartesianIndex(2, 4)
CartesianIndex(3, 4)
CartesianIndex(10, 5)
CartesianIndex(11, 4)
```

How can I update `index_left` to add +3 in the second index for all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution could be

```
index_left = findall( x -> x == 1, sol.x_assignment[:,4:6])
index_left = map(x -> x + CartesianIndex(0, 3), index_left)
```

I think you can also use `==(1)` in place of `x -> x + 1`, looks a bit nicer :)

`index_left = findall(==(1), sol.x_assignment[:,4:6])`

and the inplace version of map should work too

`map!(x -> x + CartesianIndex(0, 3), index_left, index_left)`.

An alternative could be first finding all the indices with 1 and then filtering afterwards, so smth like

```
full_index = findall(==(1), sol.x_assignment)
```

and then

```
left_index = filter(x -> x[2] <= 3, full_index)
right_index = filter(x -> x[2] > 3, full_index)
```

Comment: `index_left = filter(x->sol.x_assignment[x], CartesianIndices((axes(sol.x_assignment,1),4:6))` (also works and doesn't go over all matrix).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your `x` is:

```
using Random;Random.seed!(0);
x = rand(Bool, (5,6))
```

The first set can be found as:

```
findall(isone, @view x[:, 1:3])
```

For the second set you need to shift the results hence you want:

```
findall(isone, @view x[:, 4:6]) .+ Ref( CartesianIndex(0,3))
```

If you are searching for different value eg. `2` use `==(2)` rather than a lambda as this is faster.
Similarly `@view` allows to avoid unnecessary allocations.